# How to make your own commands

Tags: 12.04

I am new to linux.

I made a python script that takes two inputs: a directory name and a file name. The file contains a pattern in each line. The output of the script is all the files that match the pattern and are in the given directory or its subdirectories.

Now I want to be able to invoke this python script using a command, like this:

```
user@machine:~$ search directory_path file_path
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the script in ~/bin if it is for a single user. If it is for multiple users put it in /usr/local/bin.

If you put it in /usr/local/bin, have it owned by root. (Enter root password where necessary)

```
sudo cp script /usr/local/bin
sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/script
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/script
```

Ubuntu automatically puts ~/bin on your user path (you have to log out and back in or start a new log in shell) and /usr/local/bin is already on the default path.

Make sure `#! /usr/bin/env python` is at the very top of the script and that the script is executable (chmod 755)

Comment: 2 doubts.  1. If I have bash script do I need to do same as for python script     2.if I have saved my file in /usr/local/bin than I have add sudo before command???

Comment: For a bash script , add `#! /bin/bash` at the top. If you need to run the script as root, I advise the script be owned by root and you call the script with sudo.

Answer (score 2):

Make an `alias` for your command using this syntax:

```
alias COMMAND_NAME='COMMAND'
```

This way, you made your own shortcut to your command ( And of course, you can pass parameters to your alias, as it's your command, nothing less, nothing more. Also you can link this alias to run an script, for example, I made an alias to open steam + dota2 instantly like this:

```
alias steamz='sh ~/Games/steam.sh'
```

)

But, your shortcut will be removed once you close your Terminal, so to save this `alias` and use it daily, add this piece to `~/.bashrc`, this file contains commands running on each Terminal run, so if you add your `alias` definition to this file, your `alias` will be automatically defined on each Terminal run.

Good luck!